# haproxy.conf frontend/subdirectory to backend on a different host

Tags: haproxy

I have a pretty basic digital ocean container set-up to hold a personal blog (jcress.org)

I'd like jcress.org/drobot/ to forward to my octoprint server, hosted on a raspberry pi in my basement.  haproxy will handle http auth for requests originating outside the lan.

nginix serves a port i'm forwarding from the raspberry pi with ssh -R, all that seems to work.

When the request lands on the raspberry pi I see this render of the login page; filling the form and hitting log in doesn't work, and i don't see any activity in /var/log/haproxy.log
[image]

From the LAN I get:
[image]

Here's haproxy.conf

```
 defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor
        maxconn 2000
        timeout connect 5s
        timeout client  15min
        timeout server  15min

frontend public
        log /dev/log local0 debug
        bind :::80 v4v6
        bind :::443 v4v6 ssl crt /etc/ssl/snakeoil.pem
        option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1
        use_backend webcam if { path_beg /webcam/ }
        use_backend octoprint_lan if { hdr_beg(host) -i 10.0 }
        default_backend octoprint

backend octoprint_lan
        reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /(.*) \1\ /\2
        option forwardfor
        server octoprint1 127.0.0.1:5000
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503-no-octoprint.http

backend octoprint
        http-request set-header Host octopi-drobot.local
        reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /drobot/?(.*)     \1\ /\2
        option forwardfor
        server octoprint1 127.0.0.1:5000
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503-no-octoprint.http
        acl ValidOctoPrintUser http_auth(OctoPrintUsers)
        http-request auth realm OctoPrint if !ValidOctoPrintUser

userlist OctoPrintUsers
        user USAR insecure-password PASSWARD
```

here's what shows up in the haproxy log:

```
Oct 15 17:10:43 octopi-drobot haproxy[3777]: ::1:57030 [15/Oct/2019:17:10:42.938] public octoprint/octoprint1 0/0/92/45/137 200 3074 - - ---- 9/9/1/1/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not loading your CSS when you're not on the LAN.  You need to add a redirect for the CSS/JavaScript files.  Try taking a look at your OctoPrint login source HTML, and add the necessary redirects.

Comment: it's not redirecting anything, i.e. the form submission, css, the connection to the server.  is the reqrep above correct? it seems to pull the right .html but none of the other requests get to the right place.

Comment: You might be sending requests for Octoprint to the right place (i.e., haproxy sends requests for `/drobot` to Octoprint), but Octoprint itself may be configured in such a way (relative paths?) that all its content is confined to the LAN.  For example, if you need `/foo.js`, Octoprint might look for it at `https://ip.address.of.octoprint/foo.js` instead of `https://ip.address.of.octoprint/drobot/foo.js`, and the request gets lost in HAProxy

Comment: in the regex i'm trying to delete the /drobot/ portion of the uri

Comment: Can you try wrapping your trailing slash in square brackets? `reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /drobot[/]?(.*)     \1\ /\2` instead of `reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /drobot/?(.*)     \1\ /\2`

Comment: that gives a 504 error from nginx about the gateway timing out